# Mistake Deleted 6.0 folder in my iphone Simulator folder, how to make a new one?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, directory, simulator

I made a mistake and deleted all sub folders in my Simulator Folder. Now I only have Library Folder left inside my Simulator folder. When I try to create a new project and run with the simulator. I can't find projects in the simulator folder now. I tried to download Xcode again, but nothing changed.

Comment: What are You Saying I Can't Understand Tell Me what you Want

Comment: I deleted all subfolders in my Iphone Simulator Folder. i need to restore them. The subfolders has all my application in my simulator, and when i create a new project run with simulator, i cant find any application inside my simulator since the Folder is empty now.

Comment: Accept MY ans And No option for Restore Simulater SubFloder Tnanku

Comment: by the way, [link](http://imageshack.com/i/kmLS9tmYp) this is my folder now..

Comment: Its Not Way to restore Your Subfolder in Simulaater

Answer (score 0):

Check in your Xcode preferences to see if you can re-download the iOS 6.0 simulator components.

It looks like this:

[image: simulator components can be downloaded]

Unfortunately, Apple doesn't make too many simulator components available in recent releases of Xcode.  I don't have the iOS 6.X simulators available in my Xcode downloads pane, but maybe you will.

Answer (score 0):

If You Deleted all subfolders in Your Simulator. You  can't find projects in the simulator folder now. There Is No Option For Restore Simulator SubFolder.